# PostBack still losing data despite control being outside IsPostBack check

Tags: c#, session-variables, postback

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlContainer">
            <asp:Table runat="server" ID="tblMyTable" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="table table-condensed tale-bordered">
                <asp:TableHeaderRow>
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell ColumnSpan="2">
                        <h4>Header Words</h4>
                    </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                </asp:TableHeaderRow>
                **TableRows created dynamically and contain a Checkbox**
            </asp:Table>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
</div>
**Other HTML Markup**
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnClear" Text="Clear" OnClick="btnClear_Click" />
```

Page_Load

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    Build_Table();
    Session["Table"] = tblMyTable;
}
if (tblMyTable != null)
{
    pnlContainer.Controls.Remove(tblMyTable);
}
pnlContainer.Controls.Add((Table)Session["Table"]);
```

btnClear_Click

```
foreach (TableRow tableRow in tblMyTable.Rows)
{
    **more code**
}
```

I have a page that is losing data in its PostBack, despite the controls being loaded on every `Page_Load`. I have an `asp:Panel` that holds an `asp:Table`. The Table only has a header row because the rows are built dynamically in `Page_Load` via `Build_Table()` method when `!IsPostBack`. The `Build_Table()` method creates the Table just fine. We then store the Table in a Session variable called Table. Outside of `!IsPostBack` I remove the Table from the Panel control because the next line IDs will conflict (I know to avoid this I should just create the entire Table in the `Build_Table()` method). I then add the Table-casted Session variable to the Panel. Up to this point everything works fine. Table displays properly on page.

The problem is when I click the Clear button on the page the code goes to loop through each Row in the Table and uncheck the Checkbox on each Row. While debugging it says the Table has only 1 row (the static header row I have on the HTML markup). In `btnClear_Click` I even added `Table test = (Table)Session["Table"];` to make sure the Session variable is right and as expected it returns the full table.

I always struggle with PostBacks so my question is, if Session["Table"] is confirmed to hold the whole Table as intended, and that Session variable is casted and added to a container outside of `!IsPostBack`, why then is the Table empty come the first line of the `btnClear_Click` method?

Comment: after-PostBack controls life is based on ViewState, and LoadViewState is happening before PageLoad, so restoring table in PageLoad is too late. You can try reading this to understand it better https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178472(v=vs.140) but.. I feel myself 15 years younger now

Comment: Old framework or not, I enjoy asp.net : )